OPC UA Server: DiscoveryUrl and EndpointUrl
I developed an OPC UA server in C for Windows and Linux. On a Windows system the discoverUrl and the endpointUrl are the same (opc.tcp://hostname:port), but on a Linux system the discoveryUrl is "opc.tcp://hostname:port" and the endpointUrl is "opc.tcp://ip:port". When I try to connect to the server via UAExpert, this error occurs:
UAExpert Error
It is possible to connect to the server anyway, but only in UAExpert. It doesn't work in Codesys.
I tried to change the discoveryUrl to "opc.tcp://ip:port" or the endpointUrl to "opc.tcp://hostname:port" in the UA_ServerConfig struct, but neither of them worked.
Code:
pServerConfig->endpoints[0].endpointUrl = UA_String_fromChars("opc.tcp://hostname:port/");

or

UA_String_copy(&discoveryUrl ,&pServerConfig->applicationDescription.discoveryUrls[0]);
pServerConfig->applicationDescription.discoveryUrlsSize = 1;

Is there a way to change either the discoveryUrl or the endpointUrl?
